# How to force MatrixPlot to plot considering a whole color spectrum?

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to do the following:

```
Partition[Table[MatrixPlot[{{Mod[x, 30]}}, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 20], {x, 0, 29}], 5] // TableForm
```

But it outputs this:

[image]

I want it to consider all the colors in the spectrum of the temperature map. I tried `PlotRange` but it's not working. I remember there is something that forces it to do that but I can't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** Use the form `ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 29}}]` and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
Partition[
  Table[MatrixPlot[{{Mod[x, 30]}}, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 29}}], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 20], {x, 0, 29}], 
  5] // TableForm
```

[image]

**2.** Rescale the argument passed to `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]`:

```
Partition[
  Table[MatrixPlot[{{Mod[x, 30]}}, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, {0, 29}, {0, 1}]] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 20], {x, 0, 29}], 
  5] // TableForm
```

[image]

**3.** Map `ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 29}}]` to matrix entries:

```
Partition[
  Table[MatrixPlot[
     {{ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 29}}] @ Mod[x, 30]}}, 
     Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 20], {x, 0, 29}], 
  5] // TableForm
```

[image]